# How to know if a changeset was partially merged using the TFS APIs?

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, changeset

How to know if a changeset was partially merged using the Team Foundation server APIs?

One way could be to to check each and every file in changeset. If a file was merged and few files weren't merged then it's partially merged.

But is there any direct way?

Any help or code snippet would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to to check each and every file in change set.

If a file was merged and few files weren't merged then its partial merged.

But is there any direct way?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use the API but it will give you the information you want without having to manually check each file.

You can use the [tf merges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/656cs2x5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command from a visual studio command prompt

i.e.

`tf merges $/MyTeamProject/SourceBranch $/MyTeamProject/DestinationBranch /recursive`

The report produced by the command will list the changeset from the source branch and the changset of the merge. If the merge was partial then the source changeset will have a `*` next to it.